# Why MTLTexture with 2D Array doesn't work?

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, metal

I'm trying to replicate splat map technique from Unity tutorial. They use `Texture2DArray` so I created MTLTexture with this type:

```
private func createTerrainTexture(_ bundle: Bundle) -> MTLTexture {
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let names = ["sand", "grass", "earth", "stone", "snow"]

    let loader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
    let array = names.map { name -> MTLTexture in
        do {
            return try loader.newTexture(name: name, scaleFactor: 1.0, bundle: bundle, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    guard let queue = device.makeCommandQueue() else {
        fatalError()
    }
    guard let commandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer() else {
        fatalError()
    }
    guard let encoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder() else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    descriptor.textureType = .type2DArray
    descriptor.pixelFormat = array[0].pixelFormat
    descriptor.width = array[0].width
    descriptor.height = array[0].height
    descriptor.mipmapLevelCount = array[0].mipmapLevelCount
    descriptor.arrayLength = 5

    guard let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor) else {
        fatalError()
    }

    var slice = 0
    array.forEach { item in
        encoder.copy(from: item,
                     sourceSlice: 0,
                     sourceLevel: 0,
                     sourceOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                     sourceSize: MTLSize(width: item.width, height: item.height, depth: 1),
                     to: texture,
                     destinationSlice: slice,
                     destinationLevel: 0,
                     destinationOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))
        slice += 1
    }

    encoder.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.commit()
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    return texture
}
```

Here is my fragment shader function:

```
fragment half4 terrainFragment(TerrainVertexOutput in [[stage_in]],
                               texture2d_array<float> terrainTexture [[texture(0)]])
{
    constexpr sampler sampler2d(coord::normalized, filter::linear, address::repeat);
    float2 uv = in.position.xz * 0.02;
    float4 c1 = terrainTexture.sample(sampler2d, uv, 0);
    return half4(c1);
}
```

Here is Unity shader from tutorial:

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
    float2 uv = IN.worldPos.xz * 0.02;
    fixed4 c = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTex, float3(uv, 0));
    Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
    o.Metallic = _Metallic;
    o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
```

For some reason I'm getting wrong result when texture repeated in columns.

[image: Wrong texture]

Result I want to have is:

[image]

Update.
Here is how texture looks like in GPU Frame Debugger:

[image]

When I copy mipmaps like this:

```
var slice = 0
array.forEach { item in
    print(item.width, item.height, item.mipmapLevelCount)
    for i in 0..<descriptor.mipmapLevelCount {
        encoder.copy(from: item,
                     sourceSlice: 0,
                     sourceLevel: i,
                     sourceOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                     sourceSize: MTLSize(width: item.width, height: item.height, depth: 1),
                     to: texture,
                     destinationSlice: slice,
                     destinationLevel: i,
                     destinationOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))
    }

    slice += 1
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
-[MTLDebugBlitCommandEncoder validateCopyFromTexture:sourceSlice:sourceLevel:sourceOrigin:sourceSize:toTexture:destinationSlice:destinationLevel:destinationOrigin:options:]:254: failed assertion `(sourceOrigin.x + sourceSize.width)(512) must be <= width(256).'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the texture in Xcode's GPU Frame Debugger? Do all of the source textures in `array` have the same dimensions? The code allows those source textures to have mipmaps but doesn't properly copy them. You'd need to loop through the levels and copy them, too.

Comment: @KenThomases could you please advise me how to copy mipmaps? I tried to do internal loop but it fails in `copy()` method.

Comment: You loop with an index from `0..<item.mipmapLevelCount` and do the copy you're doing now, but specify that index for both the `sourceLevel:` and `destinationLevel:` parameters. If you're still having problems, edit your question to show the new code and whatever error you're getting.

Comment: @KenThomases OK, I tried to copy mipmaps but getting error.

Comment: Oh, right. My mistake. You need to adjust the size you're copying (`sourceSize:`) for the level, since each level is smaller than the one before it. The C for the width would be `max(1, item.width >> level)`. Similar for height. Not sure if it's different in Swift.

Comment: @KenThomases mipmap copying works now but I see the same result (see my screenshot). So it looks like mipmap is not the case.

Comment: My next guess is that your vertex shader is set `position` incorrectly. Show the definition of `TerrainVertexOutput`, the vertex shader code, and anything we'd need to understand the inputs to that.

Comment: @KenThomases I found problem, it was wrong position variable. Thank you for you help with mipmap anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in incorrect porting of fragment shader input variable. In original input `worldPos` was used, but I used `float4 position [[position]]` and according to Metal specification this means

> Describes the window-relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w) values for the fragment.

So position was incorrect. Here is how correct fragment shader input looks like:

```
struct TerrainVertexOutput
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 p;
};
```

And vertex function:

```
vertex TerrainVertexOutput terrainVertex(TerrainVertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                                         constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                         constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{
    TerrainVertexOutput v;

    v.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
    v.p = (scn_node.modelTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0)).xyz;

    return v;
}
```